# sp_setapprole error when threading: "Impersonate Session Security Context" cannot be called in this batch because a simultaneous batch has called it

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

When calling sp_setapprole on SQL Server 2014 from a threaded app we get the error:"Impersonate Session Security Context" cannot be called in this batch because a simultaneous batch has called it. The connections are not pooled as far as I know and a new connection is created on each call so I'm not sure where the collision is happening. Here is the test app that creates the error:

```
    using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace PleaseBreak
 {
class Program
{
    static string ConnectionString = "Data Source=<SQL DB SERVER>; Initial Catalog=<SQL DB NAME>; user id=<USER NAME>; pwd=<PASSWORD>; Enlist=false; Persist Security Info=True; Pooling=false; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; APP=<APPNAME>;";
    static int ThreadCount = 3;
    static int LoopCount = 100000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();            

        for (var i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Work));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    static void Work()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < LoopCount; i++)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                try
                {
                    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_setapprole", new SqlParameter[] 
                    { 
                        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@RETURN_VALUE", Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, DbType = DbType.Int32 },
                        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@rolename", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, DbType = DbType.AnsiString, Value = <APPROLE NAME> },
                        new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@password", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, DbType = DbType.AnsiString, Value = <APP ROLE PASSWORD> },
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I meant to type 2014, I have fixed it in the original. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that MultipleActiveResultSets was the issue. Once we added MultipleActiveResultSets=False to the connection the problem went away.